# Migrate an existing Jersey rest webapp to Atmosphere and adding push notification

Tags: rest, push-notification, jersey, atmosphere

I have a restful Jersey API server(client is mobile app). Now I need to add client online/offline detection and push notification features to the application. Is Atmosphere framework the right tool for my problem? If it is, how can I migrate the existing Jersey rest server to Atmosphere and add push notification?

Comment: what is the language on client side?

Comment: Client side includes iOS and Android (ObjectiveC and Java)

Comment: You can see a client for android here:  https://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/wasync-websockets-with-fallbacks-transports-for-android-node-js-and-atmosphere/